# How to get the image resource permalink in shortcode?

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode where I need to read a resource property. This is my shortcode `lbimg.html`:

```
{{ $img := $.Page.Resources.GetMatch (.Get "name")}}
{{$img.RelPermalink}}
```

This is how I use it:

```
{{< lbimg name="/images/test.png" >}}
```

This is what I'm getting when building the site:

> failed to render shortcode "lbimg": failed to process shortcode: "path_to_blog/layouts/shortcodes/lbimg.html:2:6": execute of template failed: template: shortcodes/lbimg.html:2:6: executing "shortcodes/lbimg.html" at : nil pointer evaluating resource.Resource.RelPermalink

I don't understand what does that mean, why the resource is `nil`?

I'm using `Hugo 0.59.1`.

The content structure is as follows:

```
blog
├── content
│   └── post
│       └── test_post
│           ├── images
│           │   └── test.png
│           └── index.md
└── ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

`{{< lbimg name="images/test.png" >}}`

My error was similar but my problem was not naming the page file `index.md`